# How to send e-mail on startup on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, startup, mailutils

I have tried a few things so far but with no success.

I modified crontab and and preceeded the command with `@reboot mail.mailutils ...`

I also created a *.sh* script, changed permission, added it to *init.d* modified configuration with `sysv-rc-config --level 3 script on` and added the necessary line to *rc.local*.

I would really appreciate if you could tell me where else to look!

I just want to send an email when I boot my Ubuntu (desktop not server) and when I turn it off.

The script that I am using is not even a script is

```
mail.mailutils -s "subject" emailaddress <<< "message"
```

Comment: Add your script to the question so others might see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you can send email. I am using mailutils to send email, the way to send email is:

```
    echo "system start" | mail -s "start" youraccount@xx.com
```

Second, add a systemd task to listening the boot and shutdown event.

1. create a file /etc/init.d/myemail, then add the following scripts.
2. sudo update-rc.d myemail defaults
3. now its done.
4. Tips: some email provider will intercept your email, since your email account is not like a common email format.

   ```
   #! /bin/sh
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          myemail
   # Required-Start: 
   # Required-Stop:
   # Default-Start:     1 2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 6
   # Short-Description: on boot and shutdown send a email.
   # Description:
   ### END INIT INFO


   PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin


   . /lib/lsb/init-functions


   case "$1" in
     start|status)
           echo "system start" | mail -s "start" youraccount@xx.com
           date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   --start" >> /var/log/myemail.log
           ;;
     restart|reload|force-reload)
           echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
           exit 3
           ;;
     stop)
           echo "system poweroff" | mail -s "poweroff" youraccount@xx.com
           date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   --stop" >> /var/log/myemail.log
           ;;
     *)
           echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
           exit 3
           ;;
   esac

   return 0
   ```

Comment: Hey! I get an error when I try the second command: 

update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/myemail

Comment: I have tell you at first step, create a file /etc/init.d/myemail. It means create a file named myemail in the directory '/etc/init.d'. Then add the scripts content from ahead to the file myemail. Check your steps.